# How could I visit StackExchange when I am on StackOverflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

How could I visit StackExchange when I am on StackOverflow? Now, I input the address of StackExchange to visit it when I am on StackOverflow. Is there another way?

Comment: @AlE. I disagree. That's a [tag:feature-request]; this is a [tag:support] question

Comment: @AlE. So? I was always under the assumption that that quality did not necessarily make questions into duplicates. See, for example, http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/506/5323 and http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1339/5323

Comment: @Shokhet I can't see AIE's suggested duplicate to see what he was suggesting, but in general the rules are a bit looser on meta than on main sites.  We don't need the same discussion on multiple posts over and over again.  So if the question (regardless of tags) can be answered by reading the comments and answers (mostly answers) on the linked question, then they really on duplicates on meta.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Makes sense, I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right-click on "StackExchange" on the upper-left of the page.  Select "Open link in new tab".  Then `www.stackexchange.com` will be open in the new tab.

Comment: Whoa. You just blew my mind with that one.

Answer (score 5):

From SO, there are a few ways that I know of; it's a bit easier to get to meta.stackexchange.com than plain old stackexchange.com:

- To MSE via dropdown:

  1. Click the Stack Exchange drop list at the left of the top bar.
  2. If Meta Stack Exchange is one of your top communities the link will be readily visible, at least to the meta.
  3. If not, you can type "Stack Exchange" in the search box there, although at that point you might as well just type it in your address bar. However, if you click "edit" in the drop down, you can add it as one of your communities.
- To MSE via bottom navigation menu:

  1. Scroll alllll the way down to the bottom of whatever page you are on.
  2. In the column on the right, there is a link to Meta Stack Exchange.
- To SE via your profile:

  1. Visit your [user profile on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621916/xshsinap).
  2. Click "[Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/5869035/xshsinap)" on the top right.
  3. You are now looking at your network profile on stackexchange.com and can navigate around from there.
- To SE via the tour page:

  1. Click "Help" on the right side of the top bar.
  2. Select "[Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)" from the drop down menu.
  3. Near the top of the tour page, just under the big Stack Overflow logo, there is a direct link to stackexchange.com.

Comment: [pacoverflow's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252997/230261) is way easier.

Comment: "way" is an understatement :D It's like a quick sentence and simple process, vs Comprehensive Sys Admin handbook for Red Hat... (yours *is* more thorough, and some people like *options*, so +1 for both)